# Horizontal scrollview within UITableview issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I created UIScrollview with in UITableViewCell. The scrollView has some pictures to display in horizontally. It works good in one row but I am loading more than one row cells, it makes an issue when one cell is replaced by other cells.

I am using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:section]`.

I also gave separate identifier for each row.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *section = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"section%@cell", indexPath.section];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:section]; 
    if (cell == nil) 
    { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:section]; 
        NSArray *pageImages = imgs; 
    }    
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"recall");
    } 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Tableview cell reusing will not work like what you think.You always have to save that state of each cells and populate it again when you scroll the tableview.remove the subviews in the cell always.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{NSString *section = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"section%@cell", indexPath.section];
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:section];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:section];
       NSArray *pageImages = imgs;
    else{NSLog(@"recall");}
return cell;
}

Comment: Thanks for replay some time empty row also display

Comment: how can i save the all states in UITableViewCell.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to give each cell a different reuse identifier. Change

```
NSString *section = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"section%@cell", indexPath.section];
```

to

```
NSString *section = @"Arbitrary";
```

Comment: Thanks for replay i tried that but it gives the same problem.First three 3 cells object created others not created.It gives empty cells.

Comment: You also should be setting the cell content inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath